# Trouble getting StateHasChanged to update an @if Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

So I'm having trouble getting my Razor page to update an if statement.

The idea is when a user selects a button, it'll recount the string looking for how many of X values there are, right now we are looking for spaces. If theres one space, I want the input field locked (the user has no reason edit it). If theres more than one space, its unlocked.

Below is the if statement holding the  tags

```
                @if (NumOfSelectedValue <= 1)
            {
                <input class="form-control-sm" value="1" style="width: 40px" disabled />
            }
            else if (NumOfSelectedValue > 1)
            {
                <input class="form-control-sm" value="@NumOfSelectedValue" style="width: 40px" />
            }
```

And here is the logic on how I thought it would be updated.

```
    public void SpaceSelected() //ive used "async task"
{
    int NumOfSelectedValue = SelectedCell.Count(x => x == ' ');//counting how many spaces there are with Linq
    Console.WriteLine(NumOfSelectedValue);//post num of spaces in the console

    //other versions ive used 
    //StateHasChanged();//update the if statement
    //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

Comment: Your razor code checks `NumOfSelectedValue`, which is presumably a field you have or is a compile time error.  The *local* variable `NumOfSelectedValue` you define in `SpaceSelected` is not representing the same thing and in fact accomplishes nothing that could impact the razor code.

Comment: ah i didnt show it but above the second chunck of code i have
public string NumOfSelectedValue { get; set; }

Comment: Yep it's a C# error-- drop `int` prefix from `NumOfSelectedValue` in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comments, you have a **public property** named `NumOfSelectedValue`.  This is separate from the **local variable** `NumOfSelectedValue` you defined in `SpaceSelected`.  Your solution is to not declare that local variable and instead just update the property:

```
public void SpaceSelected()
{
    NumOfSelectedValue = SelectedCell.Count(x => x == ' ');
    StateHasChanged();  // Probably not necessary unless you're calling this method in the background
}
```

Notice that we no longer have the `int` part in front of the assignment, which is what was declaring the variable.

Comment: I'd upvote you but I'm not cool enough.

Comment: @Nuka, glad I could help. :)